# accessing datatable and variables inside Backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

in my program i use a Datatable which is filled at loading of form. And i use backgroundworker to do some network operations. Inside doWork() of backgroundworker i need data from datatable and also object of a class that i created in loading of form. Data in datatable and class object is updated inside Dowork() and also this values from datatable and class object is updated in a listivew in ProgressChanged of backgroundworker.
Both datatable and class object is declared global to Form1.
But i read this is not thread safe.So how to use in correct to use it in thread safe way?

Comment: Take a look at locking and/or parameterized ThreadStart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass one argument from RunWorkerAsync to DoWork, and this can be an array to get it all over:

```
dim bgw as new BackgroundWorker
dim dt as DataTable
dim anything as ...
...
bgw.RunWorkerAsync(New Object() {dt, anything, ...})

...
```

inside doWork:

```
Private Sub BGW_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim dt as DataTable

    dt = TryCast(e.Argument(0), DataTable)
    ' and so on
```

As soon as you start to modify anything UI-related on a form, you can start reading about BeginInvoke and InvokeRequired. There's probably a lot out there, but maybe this question I had may be a good sample for this:
[Multithreading for a progressbar and code locations (vb.net)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533412/multithreading-for-a-progressbar-and-code-locations-vb-net/13104341)